# Mute and Unmute Button

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services

I have two function for performing mute and unmute in amazon connect. I want to know how I can make a button onclick event which performs mute on oneclick and unmute on another click? How can I invoke two methods in button onclick?

```
function muteAgent() 
{
//window.myCPP.agent.mute();
connect.core.getUpstream().sendUpstream(connect.EventType.BROADCAST,
{
event: connect.EventType.MUTE,
data: { mute: true }
});
function unmuteAgent() 
{
//window.myCPP.agent.unmute();
connect.core.getUpstream().sendUpstream(connect.EventType.BROADCAST,
{
event: connect.EventType.MUTE,
data: { mute: false }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple example without the code to actually mute or unmute.  Here is how you can achieve a toggle button than can invoke different functions;

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

// your mute button
<p><button onclick="myFunction()" id="myDIV">Mute</button></p>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Mute") {
    x.innerHTML = "Unmute";
    // Function to mute
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Mute";
 // Function to unmute
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_text

Comment: Thanks for the answer it did helped :). But if you want to keep the same result in all your tabs, what can be done?

Comment: Same result as not changing from 'mute' to 'unmute' but just keep the text as is? If so, just remove the x.innerHTML = "Unmute" and same for "mute".