# Audio mute and unmute button in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, audio

I am creating an HTML page with multiple audios. I want a mute button which can mute all audios of that page together so that even we play another audio even if it plays but we can not hear anything.

I am referring the [code mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64063480/mute-and-unmute-button).

But it only creates a Toggle button, but not mute the audio.

The audio tags used on the page are like below:

```
            <audio id="audio_playo24">
                <source src="voice/vo3.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
            </audio>
```

Can anyone please point me in the correct direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try once with this code it will work fine.

JavaScript Code

```
function toggleMute() {
   var myAudio = document.getElementById('audio_playo24');
   myAudio.muted = !myAudio.muted;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<audio id="audio_playo24" controls>
   <source src="voice/vo3.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleMute()">Mute/Unmute</a>
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: I checked you have missing attribute `controls` in audio tag. Simple use this controls will be visible.  If still want to use mute/unmute toggle with javascript control then have use `toggleMute()` function. Working example available on this URL https://jsfiddle.net/0ght2xpz

Comment: I am getting this error on console: "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function" resulting the code not working

Comment: Where are executing this code? in browser? It will work in browser for sure. Can you put your code in https://jsfiddle.net so that i can see, what mistake your are doing.

Comment: document.getElementById is working fine. Using small "d" in the ID.

Comment: Okay fine, if you will face any issue regarding this then tell me.

Comment: Perfect in Firefox.